# How to delete a certain path from $PATH on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, path, terminal

I need to get rid of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` in my `$PATH` variable on Mac OS X Lion. I opened several files, which add something to the path but do not find the location which adds the python path. Here is the output of several files and the path variable:

`echo $PATH` returns

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/friedrich/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin:/Users/friedrich/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin:/Users/friedrich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin:/Users/friedrich/.rvm/bin:/Users/friedrich/.rbenv/shims:/Users/friedrich/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

File `/etc/paths/`

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

File `~/.profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/todo-txt/2.9/bin
```

File `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# todo.txt script path
source /usr/local/Cellar/todo-txt/2.9/etc/bash_completion.d/todo_completion complete -F _todo t

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-03-01_at_21:26:56: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

The last file which adds something to the path seems to be `.bash_profile` adding `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`, so I need the file adding something one step before that.

Comment: Looking at the order of changes you need to look in /usr/local/Cellar/todo-txt/2.9/etc/bash_completion.d/todo_completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the order in which the paths are added to the `$PATH` variable(so you want to remove the third element), you can add a command like this at the end of your `.bash_profile`:

```
 export PATH=`echo $PATH | cut -d":" -f1,2,4-`
```

Comment: Just tried it which resolved in an empty $PATH. Seems to be an error in cut.

Comment: if you remove the newly added export from .bash_profile, reopen the terminal and run `echo $PATH | cut -d":" -f3 --complement` in terminal what does it output?

Comment: `cut: illegal option -- -
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]`

Comment: I have edited my post. Please check the new form of the command.

Comment: Doing a cut like thing seems *extremely* fragile to me. What happens if your $PATH changes? Items can be *pre*-prended to the path, even for duration of a single session when running a script or whatnot. Better to find the source of the entry you want removed, even if you have to do a `sudo find / -print | xargs grep <path-to-remove>` and let it run all night.

Answer (score 2):

There are yet more ways to add things to your PATH on OS X.

In addition to the `/etc/paths` file, there is a directory `/etc/paths.d`. In that directory are text files of the same format as `/etc/paths`. The lines of each file in `/etc/paths.d` are added to your PATH after the lines in `/etc/paths`, and before the stuff in `.bash_profile` (though that depends on exactly what is in `.bash_profile`).

If your unwanted Python framework path isn't in the above, there are two other places I can think to try. There are also `/private/etc/paths` and `/private/etc/paths.d`, and possibly a `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

I hope that does it for you. If it doesn't, then the workaround I would use would be to make the last command in `.bash_profile` to append `/usr/bin` to the front of your PATH. That way the Apple version of Python (which is linked to in `/usr/bin`) will be found before your framework version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can trim a fixed part of the path using parameter expansion. Add this to the end of `.bash_profile` (or at least, late enough that it is processed after the offending path is added):

```
PATH=${PATH/\/Library\/Frameworks\/Python.framework\/Versions\/2.7\/bin:}
```

(All the backslashes are unfortunate, but you at least you only have to type it once.)